# How to split many requests to chunks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, request-promise

I have a set of requests but they can not be called all simultaneously so I decided to split the set into the chucks of 10.
I am wondering how can I make 10 requests and wait for them all to complete like the example above:

```
data = []
for(mindex = 0; mindex < 1000; mindex = mindex + 10){
   request_chunk = []
   for(index = mindex+1; index < mindex+10; index++){
      request_chunk.push(api.call(requests[index]).getPromise();
   }

  data = data + waitPromiseToComplete(request_chunk);
}
```

Comment: Maybe as an alternative strategy use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck

Comment: Are you willing to use rxjs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749690/parallel-http-requests-via-forkjoin-and-response-identification

Comment: @davidmpaz is rxjs suitable for my case?

Comment: Yes it is, take a look to the link. Although you got already an answers with promises which was originally requested by you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise.all and await:

```
(async function () {
  const data = []; // always declare variables!
  for(let mindex = 0; mindex < 1000; mindex = mindex + 10){
    const request_chunk = []
    for(let index = mindex + 1; index < mindex + 10; index++){
      request_chunk.push(api.call(requests[index]).getPromise();
    }

    data = data.concat(await Promise.all(request_chunk));
  }
})();
```